# cefsharp изменить передаваемое время c#

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Доброго времени суток, не подскажите, как изменить системное время, которое передается браузером (cefsharp) сайту ? Я ставлю прокси

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-bypass-list", "127.*,192.168.*,10.10.*,193.9.162.*");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "socks5://89.23.254.231:45554");
```

Захожу на `whoer.net` и в графе "`время`" системное время отличается от локального. Можно ли как-то передать собственное значение времени ? Как вариант, меня время на самом пк, но думаю, что есть способ и по проще, спасибо